She drops her kid off at kindergarten and picks her up every day

She drops her kid off at kindergarten and picks her up every day.

This is my English translation of a Japanese sentence.
Is every day acceptable although the kid does not go to kindergarten on Sundays?
The original Japanese sentence sounds natural, but, in my translation, "from Monday to Friday/Saturday" might be better than every day.

Every day means... every day. So, no. 'Every day except Sunday' is OK though.

except you might understand from context and general knowledge that "except Sunday" is understood, because culturally you know that kindergarten never happens on Sunday.

The meaning of "every day" is ... every day (including Sunday).
But there may be a shared understanding between speaker and listener that "except Sunday" is understood, since both know there is no kindergarten on Sunday. In other countries it might be "obvious" that there's no kindergarten on Saturday, or Friday.
So yes, it is "acceptable". It might not be "true", but the listener will understand the "true" sense from shared cultural knowledge.

Thank you, @James K. In the UK, do kids normally go to kindergarten from Monday to Friday?

So do, some don't.  We tend not to talk about "kindergarten", but use expressions like "nursery", "early years education" or "reception"  School starts a year earlier than in the US (or Japan) or two years earlier in Scotland (Scotland has a completely different system to England for education)  Some kids do five days, some fewer, some don't go to nursery school at all.

Many thanks, @James K.

@Kaguyahime - In the UK, kindergartens typically have 'terms' like schools do, i.e. closed for half-term holidays (1 week) and summer and winter holidays (longer) as well, and also public holidays (8 days per year).

Thank you, @MichaelHarvey. I guess you are talking about "nursery school".

@Kaguyahime - kindergarten noun - in the UK, a school for children aged under five (when compulsory education starts), in the US, a class in school for children aged five or six (Cambridge English). Both types of school have terms.

Many thanks, @MichaelHarvey.
